# how to pull certain file type from a certain Tag

Tags: git

I need to pull certain file types - say *.exe and *.dll - from a certain tag in remote repository to my local (master).

All other files need to be ignored in this pull request, no matter they have changed or not. And I need to force this pull to overwrite existing files in my local.

Comment: Git doesn't pull files. Well, it doesn't really *pull* anything: pull = fetch + merge, so it fetches and then merges. But the main point is: Git works on a *commit by commit* basis. You fetch *commits*, which are full snapshots. Then you switch to a new commit, or merge commits. You make pull requests by making commits and asking someone else to fetch and merge those commits. Every commit has some version of every file. If you want to change only *some* files, set up your commit so that it has *their* versions of the other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure those files are actually part of your repository: dll and exe are generally part of a .gitignore file, and are not added/committed in a repo.

Second, a simpler workaround would be to clone your remote repo to a new local folder, checkout the tag, and copy the requested files from that new local folder to your current repo.
Then, from your current repo, add, commit and push.

Comment: The plan is, having an easy solution for some users to get last .exe and .dll files from Git. They are not part of the dev team and never merge or push any files. Dev team in the other side could any time update the project and generate new .exe or .dll. Those users (Beta testers) has no access to project source code to be able to compile their local machines.

Comment: @Al007 Then you don't need Git. You need an artifact referential like Nexus (https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss), which is made to store any artifactt you want (exe, dll). Those beta testers will donwnload their artifacts from Nexus: that is what it is for.